# Plugin conflict: vim-latex and abolish

Tags: plugin-vim-latex

After `:Abolish tits that is to say`, and `tits`, I get `* that is to say` with a star in front of it. This happens only when vim-latex is loaded and in .tex files.

PS. The problem seems to lie somewhere in `vim-latex/plugin/imaps.vim`.

Comment: Yep, you can't abolish tits - it's a sin.

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't use the plugin but on the readme it seems that `:Abolish` is used to create mappings with several possibilities with `{foo, bar}`. What you're trying to do is a simple abbreviation which doesn't need the plugin so maybe that's why you get a weird behavior? **Edit** I just installed it and your command works good for me. Maybe something create a conflict in your vimrc.

Comment: @statox, you also use latex suite? Abolish is still useful in this case because it provides case insensitivity. My solution now is to drop latex suite, which is messy and most of which I never used anyway.

Comment: @Lawrence: I don't usually use any of these 2 plugins I installed [latex-suite](https://github.com/gerw/vim-latex-suite) (can you confirm it's the good one?) and abolish to test your usecase and unfortunately couldn't reproduce your problem (so I can't help to find a solution, sorry). It is usually a good thing to get rid of plugins you don't really use, even if here it is not a real solution :-)

Comment: @statox, the version you tried doesn’t seem to be the original, which is here: http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net --. but it says improved, so it is probably better. thanks for trying!